# Application crashing due to NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(IBAction)send:(id)sender
{
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\rThis is a report from the Arabian Bully Box iOS mobile application:\r\rName of victim = %@ \rName of Bully = %@ \rLocation = %@ \rDate(s) of Incident = %@ \rWitnesses = %@ \rDescription = %@", nameVictom.text, nameBully.text, location.text, date.text, witness.text, description.text];

//    label.text = message;
    NSLog(@"%@", message);

    nameVictom.text = @"";
    nameBully.text = @"";
    location.text = @"";
    date.text = @"";
    witness.text = @"";
    description.text = @"";

    label.text = @"Thank you for your help.";
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    send.enabled = NO;

    NSLog(@"Start eMail");


    SKPSMTPMessage *smtpTestMessage = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
    smtpTestMessage.fromEmail = @"***@gmail.com";
    smtpTestMessage.toEmail = @"***@yahoo.com";
    smtpTestMessage.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
    smtpTestMessage.requiresAuth = YES;
    smtpTestMessage.login = @"***@gmail.com";
    smtpTestMessage.pass = @"***";
    smtpTestMessage.subject = @"Bully Box Submission";
    smtpTestMessage.wantsSecure = YES;

    smtpTestMessage.delegate = self;

    NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
        message,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey, nil];

//    NSDictionary *plainPart =  @{
//                                 message: kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
//                                 kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey: kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey
//                                 };


    smtpTestMessage.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObject:plainPart];

    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",message];

    NSLog(@"\r\r\rAbout to send\r\r\r");

    [smtpTestMessage send];
    NSLog(@"sent");
}
```

Whenever I run this, I press the "send" button, and the eMail almost sends until I come across this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-     [__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'
```

I feel as though I have tried EVERYTHING. I apologize for being so blunt, but I have been stumped on this for quite awhile! I am honestly about ready to give up. Thank you in advance for any help! Thank you for even looking at this post! xD <3

**EDIT**

Okay. So smtpTestMessage.parts is coming back nil. It is set up as a NSArray. How do I put the NSString "message" into an NSArray for smtpTestMessage.parts? Once this is solved, the application should work.

Honestly, if I can put ANYTHING in smtpTestMessage.parts, it should work. As long as it doesnt come back as nil.

Comment: Did you look at the error message?  It says you have a nil argument.  Do you know which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: "I have tried EVERYTHING", a part from reading the error message

Comment: I read the error message. I know it's because of a nil argument. I'm pretty sure the NSDictionary is not being created. But I cannot find out why!

Comment: Well where is `appendString:` being called? Add an exception breakpoint and go back up the call stack to pinpoint the exact problem.

Comment: try with patience to us the debugger for find the line with error. otherwise is difficult to understand what is wrong

Answer (score 5):

Create an exception breakpoint in the debugger (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html).   Break on it, then post the backtrace.

That is as much of an answer as anyone can give based on the evidence presented.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I've never really used this functionality of xCode before! haha.

Comment: This helped me realize that the NSArray "parts" is coming back nil.